# Python client send a LOT of data to server in realtime

Tags: python, rest, real-time

I have a python App that produces some data. And I need to send each  piece of the data to the backend (heroku + django + python). So far I use requests to do it. But it's very slow.

Is there a way to shorten time of the request? I've already added bulk request - but nevertheless it takes a lot of time.

I took a look at https://fanout.io and https://pusher.com but I failed to understand how to use it in my case.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you put it all in one request, and compress it?

Comment: I've already done it. I send a bulk of samples at once but it's far from real-time.

Comment: Maybe you can look into websockets.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: Maybe you can use python asyncio lib. Your app won't stop on sending data.